# Laravel not allowed to upload APK file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I wrote a code for uploading file in Laravel 5.2 but when i want to upload android APK file response shows not allowed and other type file like pdf,... allowed to upload

Code :

```
     if($request->hasFile('file'))
     {
        if ($request->file('file')->isValid())
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $destinationPath = storage_path('app');
            $fileName = time().'_'.rand(1111,9999).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
            $uploadFile = $this->uploadFile->save_file($fileName,$destinationPath.'/'.$fileName,env('APP_URL').'/'.Request::segment(3).'/storage/app/'.$fileName);
            $this->activities->post(trans('uploader.upload_file'));
            return $this->respondCreated([
                'fileName' =>$uploadFile->filename,
                'url' => $uploadFile->hostFile
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to see at which level it dies. Do you get to `$file->move()` line? Is the file moved?

Comment: after `if($request->hasFile('file'))` i used `dd('hello wrold');` still shows nothing but other type file works fine

Comment: ok. it means `->isValid()` is false. What does `isValid()` do?

Comment: check file in request `'file' => 'required|max:10240|mimes:application/vnd.android.package-archive,application/octet-stream`

Comment: thanks friends ,i found the problem , it is from php config in php.ini `upload_max_size=2M` , i changed to `10M` my problem solved